# Stuck retrieving parameters in sessions - GAE webapp2

Tags: python, google-app-engine, session

I'm trying to get sessions to work with Webapp2 with GAE, but I'm stuck retrieving the stored parameters. Maybe I'm overlooking the obvious.

A dressed down version of with main.py where I store a value in the webapp2 session:

```
import webapp2
from webapp2_extras import sessions
other imports...

class BaseHandler(webapp2.RequestHandler):  # Copied from Google's doc
    def dispatch(self):
        # Get a session store for this request.
        self.session_store = sessions.get_store(request=self.request)

        try:
            # Dispatch the request.
            webapp2.RequestHandler.dispatch(self)
        finally:
            # Save all sessions.
            self.session_store.save_sessions(self.response)

    @webapp2.cached_property
    def session(self):
        # Returns a session using the default cookie key.
        return self.session_store.get_session()

class MainPage(webapp2.RequestHandler):  # My main page proper
    def get(self):
        self.session['foo'] = 'bar'      # Store somehing in the session
        template_values = {

        }

        template = JINJA_ENVIRONMENT.get_template('index.html')
        self.response.write(template.render(template_values))


application = webapp2.WSGIApplication([
    ('/', MainPage, ),], debug = True)
```

My problem is how to access the value stored in the session from another module. In test.py I do the following:

```
from webapp2_extras import sessions
import main
other imports ...


class Test(main.BaseHandler):
    def post(self):
        foo1 = self.session.get('foo')
        return foo1

class ProductsPage(webapp2.RequestHandler):
    def get(self):
        foo2 = Test.post()
        ...
```

But I get the following error:
*TypeError: unbound method post() must be called with Test instance as first argument (got nothing instead)*

I just can't find the proper way to use the Test class and retrieve the value stored in the session. I must be overlooking something when using the class, but I'm stuck and can't find the way out.

Maybe somebody looking from outside will spot it easily?

Comment: Did you properly set up sessions per e.g  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14078054/gae-webapp2-session-the-correct-process-of-creating-and-checking-sessions ?  Anyway, you most assuredly can't call unbound method `Test.post` w/o having an instance of `Test` as the first arg -- that's Python 101 and totally independent of App Engine, webapp2, or sessions.  (where that `Login` comes from is a mystery).  Why do you need `Test` anyway -- why not roll up the inheritance and functionality right into `ProductsPage`?!

Comment: Hi Alex, indeed I had setup according to your link. And I wrongly copied the wrong error message. It's now corrected: Test instead of Login. And I see what you mean, I need an instance of Basehandler in products.py. It works in main, but I'm banging my head on how the create one within products.py. Any ideas?

Comment: I think you should have `ProductsPage` itself subclass `main.BaseHandler`, so it will have its own `self.session` to use.  I'm perplexed that your `MainPage` works without subclassing `BaseHandler`, by the way!

Comment: Hi Alex, found the solution. I posted it below. You suggestions gave me the clue how to look further. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking further I found a post that helped me
[GAE webapp2 session handling not working when putting basehandler to a different file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19331815/gae-webapp2-session-handling-not-working-when-putting-basehandler-to-a-different?rq=1)

After some tinkering here's the recipe that worked for me to setup a session in webapp2 and share the session among different .py files. Hope it saves others some time.

1) Create **basehandler.py**, this will need to be imported by all .py files using the session. This is straight from Google's documentation:

```
import webapp2
from webapp2_extras import sessions

class BaseHandler(webapp2.RequestHandler):
    def dispatch(self):
        # Get a session store for this request

        self.session_store = sessions.get_store(request = self.request)

        try:
            webapp2.RequestHandler.dispatch(self)
        finally:
            self.session_store.save_sessions(self.response)

    @webapp2.cached_property
    def session(self):
        # Returns a session using the default cookie key
        return self.session_store.get_session()
```

2) Create **main.py** importing BaseHandler. In my case I store a value in the session:

```
import os
import urllib
import webapp2
import jinja2
from basehandler import BaseHandler


JINJA_ENVIRONMENT = jinja2.Environment(
    loader=jinja2.FileSystemLoader(os.path.dirname(__file__)),
    extensions=['jinja2.ext.autoescape'])

class MainPage(BaseHandler):
    def get(self):

    self.session['foo'] = 'bar'    # Store a value in the session
                                   # you can store more than one :-)


    # Define values that will be passed onto the template 
    template_values = {
        'title': 'TITLE'
    }

    # search for an appropriate template and render it. 
    template =      JINJA_ENVIRONMENT.get_template('./templates/index.html')
    self.response.write(template.render(template_values))

config = {}
config['webapp2_extras.sessions'] = {   
'secret_key': 'my-super-secret-key'
}

application = webapp2.WSGIApplication([
    ('/', MainPage)
], config = config, debug = True)
```

3) Create **another.py** taking care to also import BaseHandler and use the same secret key. Here you can retrieve the value stored by main.py or any other .py file sharing the same session:

```
import os
import urllib
import webapp2
import jinja2
from basehandler import BaseHandler


JINJA_ENVIRONMENT = jinja2.Environment(
    loader=jinja2.FileSystemLoader(os.path.dirname(__file__)),
    extensions=['jinja2.ext.autoescape'])

class AnotherPage(BaseHandler):
    def get(self):

    foo1 = self.session.get('foo')

    # Now go and do something with foo1, even store a new value as in main.py
    # ...
    # ...

    # Define values that will be passed onto the template 
    template_values = {
        'title': 'TITLE'
    }

    # search for an appropriate template and render it. 
    template =      JINJA_ENVIRONMENT.get_template('./templates/additional.html')
    self.response.write(template.render(template_values))

config = {}
config['webapp2_extras.sessions'] = {   
'secret_key': 'my-super-secret-key'
}

application = webapp2.WSGIApplication([
    ('/', AdditionalPage)
], config = config, debug = True)
```